# Flutter correct way to deal with singleton

Tags: flutter

I understand that ideally if you want to pass around some value like user profile, `InheritedWidget` comes into play.
 But since `InheritedWidget` can't be accessed from `initState` (I got error).
If you need to access user profile in `initState`, how should I handle this?
Should I create static variable, `SharedPreferences` or any other way?
Is there a way to do this with `InheritedWidget`?

Comment: Use `didChangeDependencies` method instead of initState

Comment: Thank you  I didn’t know that would work!